# How do I get my Spring-JUnit test to think its running in a GenericApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I’m using `Spring 3.2.6.RELEASE`, `JUnit 4.11`, and `DWR 3.0.0-rc2`.  My question is, when running a Spring-JUnit integration test, how can I simulate things being run in a `org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext`?

I tried this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml", "classpath:dwr-context.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyServiceIT 
{}
```

in which my **“dwr-context.xml”** file is set to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

  <dwr:configuration>
    <dwr:convert class="java.lang.StackTraceElement" type="bean"/>
  </dwr:configuration>
  <dwr:annotation-config id="annotationConfig" />
  <dwr:annotation-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco" scanDataTransferObject="true" scanRemoteProxy="true" />
  <dwr:url-mapping />
  <dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="false" /> 

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    <property name="urlMap">
      <map>
        <entry key="/dwr/**" value-ref="dwrController" />
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean> 
</beans>
```

However, all my JUnit tests ultimately die with the below exception:

> (“java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport
>   instance [org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController@11297ba3] does
>   not run in a WebApplicationContext but in:
>   org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4e513d61”).

If I could figure out how to trick the system into running in a `GenericApplicationContext` I’d get past this issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dwrHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dwrController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController@11297ba3] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4e513d61: startup date [Mon Jan 27 09:43:45 CST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dwrController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController@11297ba3] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4e513d61: startup date [Mon Jan 27 09:43:45 CST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
        at org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(DwrHandlerMapping.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController@11297ba3] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4e513d61: startup date [Mon Jan 27 09:43:45 CST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getServletContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:124)
        at org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController.afterPropertiesSet(DwrController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 53 more
```

Comment: Your questions is wrong: Your problem is that you are running in a GenericApplicationContext, but you need a WebApplicationContext for your Dwr* beans.

Comment: HI..were u able to solve this issue..if so could provide a sample..

Comment: @EvaMariam In my case the problem was solved by adding WebAppConfiguration annotation in test class

Comment: @EvaMariam it works, tank you.

Answer (score 20):

I came across same error and fixed it adding 
`@WebAppConfiguration` in a Test class, as follows:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.arpit.jsr.config.DataConfig;
import com.arpit.jsr.config.WebConfig;

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebConfig.class, DataConfig.class })
public class ServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testSayHello() {
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello world!", "Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This fix worked for me when I upgraded from Spring 4.2 to 4.3 and some of my tests started failing with the same error.