# When testing in main function, it goes wrong in SpringMVC configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just want to test in main function about a small spring application, but it goes wrong seemingly in SpringMVC configuration .
This is my SpringMVC configuration in `spring/spring-mvc.xml` file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/BasePlu/**" location="classpath:/static/BasePlu/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/Lib/**" location="classpath:/static/Lib/" />

<bean id="natureRepository" class="com.autumnframework.blog.repository.NatureRepositoryImpl">
</bean>
```

This is my test code in `Test.java` file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath:/spring/spring-mvc.xml");

    Repository repository = context.getBean(NatureRepositoryImpl.class);
    System.out.println("4. " + repository.getAllObjects());
}
```

The wrong detail like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [static/BasePlu/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@43bd930a]]] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a86f2f1: startup date [Wed Nov 15 10:31:23 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at Test.main(Test.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [static/BasePlu/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@43bd930a]]] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a86f2f1: startup date [Wed Nov 15 10:31:23 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getServletContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.initContentNegotiationStrategy(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.afterPropertiesSet(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:268)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585)
... 12 more
```

I comment the two lines in `spring/spring-mvc.xml` file:

```
<!--<mvc:resources mapping="/BasePlu/**" location="classpath:/static/BasePlu/" />-->
<!--<mvc:resources mapping="/Lib/**" location="classpath:/static/Lib/" />-->

<bean id="natureRepository" class="com.autumnframework.blog.repository.NatureRepositoryImpl">
</bean>
```

It can run successfully, but I don't know why it can run successfully in this way.

Comment: Can you share more details on why you ended up with this `spring-mvc.xml`  configuration to be run in a standalone application? Is it that the application needs to be run as web and standalone both; or want to do some unit testing or some other reason, it would help in responding better.

Comment: I just want to do a unit testing. It doesn't matter commenting the two lines in this unit testing.

Comment: For unit testing, I recommend using JUnit, so that you are not touching the code/configuration you are testing. Some pointers here,  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388482/how-do-i-get-my-spring-junit-test-to-think-its-running-in-a-genericapplicationco`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two MVC resources need to be run in a `WebApplicationContext` but you are running it within a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` which doesn't **implement** the `WebApplicationContext`. The error message in the stack trace states this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [static/BasePlu/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@43bd930a]]] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a86f2f1: startup date [Wed Nov 15 10:31:23 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

I haven't tried creating a `WebApplicationContext` before within a main but you could attempt to use [XmlWebApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/XmlWebApplicationContext.html) instead and see if you have better luck.

If you are just looking for a way to test other spring functionality outside of MVC enabled stuff then you could do as you did and comment out the mvc resources or have two XML configurations. One for your web app and one for the main app.